# Format numbers for human consumption

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to add thousands/millions comma separator to my code. I want to display a comma separator for the fields 'How much loan?' and 'Your Credit'? I am using d3.js.

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/gfo46te1/39/

It is said that I should use `d3.format` but I can't get it to work inside my calculator.

```
var myNumber = 22400;
d3.format(',')(myNumber);
```

JavaScript:

```
var inputValues = {
    price: {
        _value: 5000,
        set value(val) {
            this._value = parseFloat(val);
            var tiv = inputValues.trade_in_value.value;
            var cdp = inputValues.cash_down_payment.value;

            if(this._value < tiv + cdp) {
                if(this._value > tiv) {
                    inputValues.cash_down_payment.value = this._value - tiv;
                } else {
                    inputValues.cash_down_payment.value = 0;
                    inputValues.trade_in_value.value = this._value;
                }
            }
        },
        get value() {
            return this._value;
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 500000,
        step: 1,
        reset: function () {
            this._value = 500000;
        }
    },
    cash_down_payment: {
        _value: 6000,
        set value(val) {
            this._value = parseFloat(val);
            var sum = this._value + inputValues.trade_in_value.value;
            if(sum > inputValues.price.value) {
                inputValues.trade_in_value.value = inputValues.price.value - this._value;
            }
        },
        get value() {
            return this._value;
        },
        min: 0,
        get max() {
            return inputValues.price.value;
        },
        step: 500,
        reset: function () {
            this._value = 6000;
        }
    },

};
```

Answer (score -1):

- if people would only look at the DevTools console to see if the browsers barks.

  ```
  var commaFormat = d3.format(',');

  this._value = formatComma(parseFloat(val));
  ```
- How many tool tips do you need?
- You can't get ',' characters in the `input` box

  ```
  <input type="number" class="calc__input" placeholder="Ile chcesz pożyczyć" min="0" max="500000" step="1">
  ```
- to get a comma in the Credit `div` convert the number using the `d3.format()` generator

  ```
  document.querySelectorAll('.chart__description-value')
      .forEach(function (valueWrapper) {
          var value = legendData[valueWrapper.classList[1]];
          valueWrapper.textContent = formatComma(Math.round(value));
      });
  ```
- Where is the Reset Button?

Comment: What about blank space in input field ? http://jsfiddle.net/gfo46te1/145/

Comment: sorry like here http://jsfiddle.net/gfo46te1/147/ there is a blank space between thousands